# WORDPRESS: PHP message: Error Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Try installing this plugin for WordPress: Crayon Syntax Highlighter

This error came out:

> 2018/08/25 08:12:19 [error] 13010#13010: *4875262 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889" while reading response header from upstream, client: MY_IP, server: MY_WEB, request: "GET /wp-admin/plugins.php?action=error_scrape&plugin=crayon-syntax-highlighter%2Fcrayon_wp.class.php&_wpnonce=2c7c7334cc HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "MY_WEB", referrer: "https://MY_WEB/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin=crayon-syntax-highlighter%2Fcrayon_wp.class.php"

and now this error comes out at all times:

> 2018/08/25 09:56:52 [error] 7054#7054: *2403 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Error Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta SELECT DISTINCT  wp_posts.ID  FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND MATCH (post_title,post_content) AGAINST ('test test')  AND wp_posts.post_date < '2018-08-25 04:56:52'  AND wp_posts.post_date >= '2015-08-26 04:56:52'  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'  AND wp_posts.ID != 96174  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page')      LIMIT 0, 6  realizada por require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, paged_comments_alter_source, eval, the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, crp_content_filter, get_crp, get_crp_posts_id" while reading upstream, client: MY_IP, server: MY_WEB, request: "GET /software/test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "MY_WEB", referrer: "https://WY_WEB/general/test"

The web works but with that error in the logs.

I have php 7, Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0 + deb9u1 Debian 9.1, WordPress 4.9.6

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory limit that wordpress uses. You can add the following code to your **wp-config.php** file.

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

*Note that the **1024M** is just an example and you can adjust this up or down depending on your system. You should find out what the default php memory_limit is first and adjust up incrementally until it resolves your issue.

From the command line:

```
php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep memory_limit
```

Using a phpinfo() function:

Add a file in your wordpress root directory which contains:

```
<?php phpinfo; ?>
```

... and open in your browser **http://localhost/.phpinfo.php** and look for the **memory_limit** value. Delete this file when your done as it can be a security risk.

---

As for the second error, add a FULLTEXT index on the table where 'post_title' and 'post_content' are located:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD FULLTEXT(`post_title`,`post_content`);
```

Comment: I want to fix the second error. The first one is from the Crayon Syntax Highlighter plugin, which I will not install anymore.

Comment: memory_limit: 512M, database weighs over 2 gigabytes.

Comment: @avi2018 You could probably use a 1G overhead:
so add 
`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1G' );` in your wp-config.php file

Comment: @avi2018  The two errors are not related though it may seem that way. You could try reactivating the Crayon Syntax Highlighter plugin after you add wp-config fix.

Comment: The second error appeared after wanting to activate that plugin. It seems that it stayed in the middle of the process and left errors in the database.

This command fixes the second error: ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD FULLTEXT (` post_title`, `post_content`);

I can not activate the plugin, I do not have much memory in the system to load the entire database as requested by that plugin.

Thanks for the help, the problem is fixed (2nd)

Comment: You also may want to re-evaluate using the MATCH AGAINST query in question: [link]https://hackernoon.com/dont-waste-your-time-with-mysql-full-text-search-61f644a54dfa